# About 10-fold cross validation train/test split

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, validation

So, I want to do 10 fold CV. After I googled it, all of the websites I've found told me that to do the split, take 1 fold as test and the rest as train. But my professor told me another way. She told me to take 1 fold as train and 1 fold as test (and repeat until 10). So in 10 fold, the way she meant is:

1. Model1: Fold1 (Train) + Fold2 (Test)
2. Model2: Fold1 (Train) + Fold3 (Test)

And so on until

9. Model9: Fold1 (Train) + Fold10 (Test)

After that continue to Fold2 as train

10. Model10: Fold2 (Train) + Fold1 (Test)
11. .............. Fold2 (Train) + Fold10 (Test)

It continues until it reaches: Fold10 (Train) + Fold9 (Test). So there is 10x9 iteration until it finished.

I told her the former way (take 1 as test and the rest as train) but she said that the latter way (her way) is more valid/stronger and made the model robust.

So I'm wondering, is her way of doing the CV correct?
(Excuse my english, btw)

Comment: If your professor meant it in the way you are describing it, it is a bad way for x-validation because each model uses only 10% data. Usually you would run 10 models (plus the final model).

Comment: Is this longitudinal data, where rows are not independent of one another or is this IID data?

Comment: @akash87 I'm sorry I can't determine which it is. My dataset have 250 rows and 9 attributes which are RGB values. Each have 3 values (R1-R3, G1-G3, B1-B3). And 1 target column that contain 3 classes. So, I think it is IID data? Because they are independent of one another

Answer (score 1):

I think what you describe as $k$-fold cross-validation is fine.

I would urge you to use freely available and established references in your work instead of websites; websites might be excellent at times but it can be hard to convince people of their quality and/or detect "mistakes" when starting in ML. For example, on the matter of cross-validation:

- Hastie et al. (2009) [*Elements of Statistical Learning*](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/), Sect. 7.10 *Cross-Validation*,
- Shalev-Shwartz & Ben-David (2014) [*Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms*](https://www.cse.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/index.html), Sect. 11.2.4 *$k$-Fold Cross Validation* and
- Bishop (2006) [*Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/pattern-recognition-machine-learning/), Sect. 1.3. *Model Selection*

can all serve as authoritative, well-established and widely used references that will withstand academic scrutiny. For that matter, probably most of the areas covered in an  undergraduate ML course will be included in one of these books.

On a purely interpersonal level: Your lecturer might have a particular application in  mind. Politely ask him/her to point you to some relevant material.

Comment: Thank you so much for the references! But is it true that my professor way is more valid and made the model robust like she said?

Comment: I am glad I could help. Without sugarcoating it, what your professor described does not appear to be a very standard approach. But as I said maybe there is a particular application so you should definitely ask for some material.

Comment: okay, will do. thanks for the assistance!